# How to add highcharts export.js in d3 charts for export

Tags: d3.js, svg, highcharts, export, export-to-pdf

I want to use highcharts export.js module in d3 charts for downloading d3 chart as PNG,PDF and JPEG .Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use tools for D3.js for exporting to images (like [this one](https://github.com/shawnbot/d3-to-png)) ? exporting.js (not export.js!) requires Highcharts chart to generate context menu and well.. to generate a Highcharts chart, you need Highcharts license.

Comment: @PawełFus That worked..!! Thank You ..